# How to combine and split cells in tabulator.js

Tags: tabulator

I need to create a complex tabular structure. The table is built using the tabulator.js library. But I can not find in the documentation how to combine or split the cells.

I want to create something like this:

`|---------------------------------------------|
|    TITLE    |   TERM START   |   TERM END   |
|---------------------------------------------|
|             |  term_1_start  |  term_1_end  |
|    year_1   |-------------------------------|
|             |  term_2_start  |  term_2_end  |
|---------------------------------------------|
|    year_2   |          not avalibe          |
|---------------------------------------------|`

Or there may be some other library that can easily handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently not feasible because Tabulator.js uses **DIV**s to create **HTML** elements.
Unfortunately div has not ***colspan/rowspan*** attribute.
If you see the Developer [Roadmap](https://trello.com/b/rPZ0Yavc/tabulator-roadmap) you can check the Version 5.0 which contain that the following description:

1. Coll Span Functionality
2. Row Span Functionality

Answer (score 1):

Would column groups work for you?:
http://tabulator.info/examples/4.3#column-groups